# How can i sort highchart bars by in descending amount

Tags: jquery, highcharts, bar-chart

This is my method and i am getting data from mysql in descending order but highchart always change the bars randomly but i want to sort chart according to amount descending by using this method.

Can anyone help me please i want to sort bars by using options variable.

```
$(function () {

            var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'graphbarchart',
                type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Top 10 Buildings',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: '',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [],
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                reversedStacks: false,
                labels: {
                    overflow: 'justify',
                    formatter: function () {
                        return this.value;
                    }
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        this.x +': '+ this.y;
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false,
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -10,
                y: 100,
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            credits: {
                  enabled: false
            },
            plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            },
            series: []
        }


        $.getJSON('<?php echo base_url(); ?>welcome/barchartdata/15', function(json) {
            options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
            options.series[0] = json[1];
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });


 });
```

Comment: is the `json[0]` and `json[1]` generated randomly?

Comment: Check This image please i want these blue bars to be sorted descending order and also i want that Remaining should be at end
http://demo.cybussolutions.com/bargraph.png

Comment: It could make others find issue easier if you could make your code self contained or try to use like jsfiddle to put your code. I suspect that the data is out of order.

Comment: Where are you sorting your data? Could you show us the output from your getJSON? Do you have any errors in your console (Developer Tools)?